# facebook page tab accessing non ssl url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ssl

Whenever our client access the page tab app, facebook gives her ssl error. My page tab urls are both https://
as well as what I entered in adding the facebook app to the fan page - I used the url of add to page dialog as given by facebook in their docs.

I tried it personally and it's working perfectly: no ssl errors, no runtime error. What would be the cause of this? Is this because on our server disabling port 80? Is this a facebook bug? Would most of the end user be accessing facebook.com without ssl?

I'm really confused here.

Comment: There was a bug for either canvas or page tabs (not both, I think it was page tabs), where they replaced https:// with http:// when calling your app if you entered an HTTPS URL for the HTTP URL value – don’t know if that’s fixed yet. But why are you not offering HTTP as well? It’s the user’s choice, so why not respect that?

Comment: Alternative solution could be to make a basic HTML page available via HTTP (and give that as HTTP URL), that does nothing more then redirect to the HTTPS version of your app on Facebook via JavaScript.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, our server admin told me that he disabled PORT 80, therefore, he disabled HTTP access since it's a vulnerability. That's why I didn't put HTTP on the HTTP Url field.

Comment: If serving HTTP on port 80 was a “vulnerability”, then 99.99999% percent of the web would be vulnerable …

Comment: I see. I tried your suggestion to put HTTP where it should be put. Client still sees "Content feature is not available" whenever she access the page tab. So, it's not on the server and it's a bug on facebook, just like what you commented?

Comment: If you put an HTTP URL into the field for the HTTP address, then Facebook will try to load that into the iframe – if that doesn’t work, then I think it must be something with your site. Is your page accessible via HTTP directly in the browser? It does not automatically redirect to HTTPS or something? (Redirect directly on HTTP level, that way you would lose the POST data you receive from Facebook.)

Comment: Looks like the client's browser doesn't automatically redirect to HTTPS but my browser does.